# Print CSS does not work on firefox and safari

Tags: css, printing, media

i've included a css for the print like that:

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="css/print.css" type="text/css" />
```

CSS:

```
@media print{ 

 ....

}
```

On Chrome the css works well but on firefox and safari the print shows only the logo of the webpage...

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Since you've provided nothing useful, like the actual css or the html it applies to, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

The problem was a class "animate" use for the animation of the elements in the page.

i just do that:

```
    @media print{ 

     .animated{
      opacity: 1 !important;
       }

    }
```